# Check for empty datatable in UiPath

Tags: uipath

I am new to UiPath and in my sample application I wanted to check whether a DataTable is empty or not. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it using a **If** activity with the following condition.

```
datatable.Rows.Count = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending wether you consider empty as null value or no data inside, you can check it with this conditional statement:
`datatable Is Nothing OrElse datatable.Rows.Count = 0`

Answer (score -1):

You can check, if the value of `datatable.Rows.Count = 0`.

Good luck!

Comment: How is this different to the previous answer?